# Cannot upload play application to dokku, gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

Tags: playframework-2.0, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

Cannot deploy play application to dokku instance. The output of git push is as follow:

```
    Writing objects: 100% (500/500), 269.54 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 500 (delta 217), reused 484 (delta 209)
-----> Cleaning up ...
-----> Building myapplcation ...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Play 2.x - Scala app detected
remote: 
remote: gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote: tar: Child returned status 1
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

As far as I remember, this used to work, but after I recreated my digital ocean droplet, it stopped working. Anyone experienced this before? Or any help how to investigate the logs would be helpful, I can't find any more information about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was bound to IPv6 enablement. After not using this option, everything works.